# Inno Setup: how to set Setup section's directive

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

first of all sorry for my bad English.

I'm working on a setup: if it's the first time that install the program, I can't use Network path but only fixed drive so directive `AllowNetworkDrive` has to be `AllowNetworkDrive=no`; else, if the program is already installed, I have to update it and allow network drive so I need `AllowNetworkDrive=yes`.

At the begin, I use `AllowNetworkDrive=no`, in the `[Code]` section, if I check that the program is already installed, I have to set it to `AllowNetworkDrive=yes`.

At the moment, I'm working in this way: I've set `AllowNetworkDrive=no` in the `[Setup]` section; in the `[Code]` section, I've done this:

```
const

  DRIVE_UNKNOWN = 0; // The drive type cannot be determined.
  DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR = 1; // The root path is invalid. For example, no volume is mounted at the path.
  DRIVE_REMOVABLE = 2; // The disk can be removed from the drive.
  DRIVE_FIXED = 3; // The disk cannot be removed from the drive.
  DRIVE_REMOTE = 4; // The drive is a remote (network) drive.
  DRIVE_CDROM = 5; // The drive is a CD-ROM drive.
  DRIVE_RAMDISK = 6; // The drive is a RAM disk.


function GetDriveType( lpDisk: String ): Integer;
external 'GetDriveTypeA@kernel32.dll stdcall';

[...]

testdrive := Copy(WizardForm.DirEdit.Text, 1, 3);
if (GetDriveType(testdrive) <> DRIVE_FIXED) then
begin
  MsgBox('Non è possibile effettuare l''installazione su questa unità.'+#13#13+'Scegliere un''unità locale fissa.', mbError, mb_ok);
  Result := False;
end;
```

Any other solutions? Is there an easier way? Thank you!

Comment: It seems, you're out of luck with using `{code:...}` scripted constants for `AllowNetworkDrive` and `AllowUNCPath` directives. They should be known when the installer is compiled.

Comment: So, what i have to do?

Comment: As TLama said, you can't change that setting programmatically.  So your choices are either to release two different installers or to use `AllowNetworkDrive=yes` combined with something like the code you have above.